# Gerrit ls-groups -v -q failes fatal: "-q" is not a valid option

Tags: gerrit

I am referring this [gerrit](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-ls-groups.html) forum to list the group information.

```
# ssh -p 29418 gerrit@review-site.com gerrit ls-groups --verbose -q proj-group
fatal: "-q" is not a valid option
```

Even with `--owned` option it shows same error.

```
# ssh -p 29418 gerrit@review-site.com gerrit ls-groups --owned --verbose -q proj-group
fatal: "-q" is not a valid option
```

And for even `administrator` group it doesn't work.

```
# ssh -p 29418 gerrit@review-site.com gerrit ls-groups --verbose -q Administrators
fatal: "-q" is not a valid option
```

`Gerrit version is 3.2.3` Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is wrong. Use the "--group" option instead:

```
ssh -p 29418 gerrit@review-site.com gerrit ls-groups --group proj-group
```

To get more info execute:

```
ssh -p 29418 gerrit@review-site.com gerrit ls-groups --help
```